# How do I call a java class that opens a CLI with the Process-Builder and reads/writes the Input-/Outputstream of this? Wrapper? Adapter?

Tags: java, wrapper

I'm writing my bachelor-thesis and I'm trying to describe the class I wrote, but I'm not sure if I'm using the right term.

To communicate via Bluetooth-Low-Energy (BLE) on my Raspberry Pi, I can open gatttool (a tool from the bluez-stack) in the command-line and write & read & do-my-stuff. Since I didn't find any BLE-Java-Class, I wrote my own class, that basically opens gatttool with the Processbuilder and writes some commands and reads/analyzes/reacts-to the Inputstream.

How do I call such a class? Is this a wrapper? Or an adapter?

Comment: I am interested in the topic, or you can specify commands which are sending to the system? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find foxite.com definitions and clarifications the most satisfying. Here it is in this case: http://weblogs.foxite.com/andykramek/2007/01/07/design-patterns-adapters-and-wrappers/

Your solution is an **adapter** since it is a separate (?) class which enables you to reach the needed functionality through a not tightly connected API.